# High Charts windrose from API data (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, api, highcharts, weather

I'm quite new here (and to web development in general), so please forgive any misuses that I perpetuate... I'm trying to create a basic windrose plot with data returned (in JSON) from the MesoWest Mesonet API service. I'm using HighCharts (or attempting to), and cannot quite get it to work. Perhaps this is due to my methodology of obtaining the data from the API itself as I'm a complete amateur in this regard. The following is the Javascript code, followed by the HTML for the page. Could someone please take a look and let me know what I've done wrong? Nothing displays on the page when I attempt to load it. In addition, if you're curious as to the specifics of an API call for MesoWest, like the one I've employed here, please see http://mesowest.org/api/docs/
The .js script:

```
var windrose = {
divname: "windrosediv",
tkn: "eecfc0259e2946a68f41080021724419",
load:function()
{
    console.log('loading')
    if (!window.jQuery) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    setTimeout(pollJQuery, 100)
    return
 }
 this.div = $("#"+this.divname);
 this.request('WBB');
 },
 pollJQuery:function()
 {
    if (!window.jQuery) {
       setTimeout(pollJQuery,100);
    } else {
        load();
    }
  },
  request:function(stn){
     console.log("making a request")
     $.getJSON(http://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/nearesttime?callback=?',
     {
       stid:stn,
       within:1440,
                   units:'english',
       token:windrose.tkn
      }, this.receive);
  },
  receive:function (data)
     {
      console.log(data,windrose);
      stn = data.STATION[0]
      dat = stn.OBSERVATIONS
      spd += Math.round(dat.wind_speed_value_1.value)
      dir += dat.wind_direction_value_1.value
     windDataJSON = [];
for (i = 0; i < dir.length; i++) {
    windDataJSON.push([ dir[i], spd[i] 
    ]); 
        },
     }
  $(function () {
    var categories = ['0', '45', '90', '135', '180', '225', '270', '315'];
$('#container').highcharts({
      series: [{
        data: windDataJSON
    }],
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Wind Rose'
    },
    pane: {
        size: '85%'
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        type: "",
        tickInterval: 22.5,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return categories[this.value / 22.5] + 'Â°';
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        endOnTick: false,
        showLastLabel: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Frequency (%)'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value + '%';
            }
        },
        reversedStacks: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            shadow: false,
            groupPadding: 0,
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }
    }
});
```

});

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js">`enter code     </script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js">    </script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 420px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<p class="ex">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://home.chpc.utah.edu/~u0675379/apiDemos/windTest.js"></script>
</p>
</html>
```

I appreciate any guidance in this regard, thanks!!! 
-Will

Comment: Are there any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: Also, can you post the contents of your windDataJSON object as it looks after the for loop that populates it?

Comment: I apologize @HalvorStrand, but as I mentioned I am quite the rookie in this regard. What do you mean the javascript console? Where is that located?

Comment: @jlbriggs, I also am not sure if the object was populated completely correct. The full query that is usually used would be: 
http://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/nearesttime?stid=wbb&token=eecfc0259e2946a68f41080021724419&within=1440
I wrote this js from an example widget posted on the MesoWest API example page. Perhaps I didn't populate the object fully correctly within my loops? This was my first attempt ever in this medium.

Comment: 1) The console is built into your browser, and if there are any javascript errors, they will be displayed there. Google how to view the console for your particular browser.

Comment: 2) between finding any javascript errors, and determining that your loop has resulted in a properly formatted data array, you'll cover the vast majority of your potential problems.

Comment: 3) use console.log(windDataJSON) to view the output of your data array in the console

Comment: Many thanks @jlbriggs, this is incredibly helpful. I think I'll be able to get the specifics hashed out through that now, but will post any further questions that come up. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

@W.Howard, I think the problem here is how you are treating and preparing the JSON response from the API. Consider the following JavaScript to retrieve and parse out the data:

```
/*
 * Helper function
 * scalarMultiply(array, scalar)
 */
function scalarMultiply(arr, scalar) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] * scalar;
    }
    return arr;
}


/*
 * getQuery(station, api_token)
 */
    function getQuery(station, mins, api_token) {

        $.getJSON('http://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/timeseries?callback=?', {
                /* Specify the request parameters here */
                stid: station,
                recent: mins, /* How many mins you want */
                obtimezone: "local",
                vars: "wind_speed,wind_direction,wind_gust",
                jsonformat: 2, /* for diagnostics */
                token: api_token
            },
            function(data) {

                try {
                    windSpeed = data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.wind_speed_set_1;
                    windDir = data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.wind_direction_set_1;
                    windGust = data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.wind_gust_set_1;
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log("Data is invalid. Check your API query");
                    console.log(this.url);
                    exit();
                }

                /* Convert from knots to mph */
                windSpeed = scalarMultiply(windSpeed, 1.15078);
                //windGust = scalarMultiply(windGust, 1.15078);

                /* Create and populate array for plotting */
                windData = [];
                for (i = 0; i < windSpeed.length; i++) {
                    windData.push([windDir[i], windSpeed[i]]);
                }

                /* Debug */
                // console.log(windData);
                console.log(this.url);

                plotWindRose(windData, mins);
            })
    };
```

What we had now is an 2D array with wind direction and wind speed that we can pass to the plotting function.  Below is the updated plotting function:

```
/*
 * Plot the wind rose
 * plotWindRose([direction, speed])
 */
    function plotWindRose(windData, mins) {

        /*
         * Note:
         * Because of the nature of the data we will accept the HighCharts Error #15.
         * --> Highcharts Error #15 (Highcharts expects data to be sorted).
         *     This only results in a performance issue.
         */
        var categories = ["0", "45", "90", "135", "180", "225", "270", "315"];

        $('#wind-rose').highcharts({
            series: [{
                name: "Wind Speed",
                color: '#cc3000',
                data: windData
            }],
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                polar: true
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Wind Direction vs. Frequency (Last ' + mins/60. + ' hours)'
            },
            pane: {
                size: '90%',
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 100,
                text: "Wind Direction"
            },
            xAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 360,
                type: "",
                tickInterval: 45,
                tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return categories[this.value / 45] + '\u00B0';
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                endOnTick: false,
                showLastLabel: true,
                title: {
                    text: 'Frequency (%)'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value + '%';
                    }
                },
                reversedStacks: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    shadow: false,
                    groupPadding: 20,
                    pointPlacement: 'on'
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

You can see it all here at https://gist.github.com/adamabernathy/eda63f14d79090ab1ea411a8df1e246e . Best of luck!